# List with item changed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, collections

I need to create a list in c# with three list inside. One with the new added items, other with the items that have been updated and other one with the removed items.
I have created one class inheriting from ObservableCollection where T is INotifyPropertyChanged and it has the three list I have talked. Everything works correctly, but I have a problem. I want this list to be send to a WCF service, so it is serialized-deserialized and here is my problem. After the serialization, every item is included in the new items list.

Any solution? Is there any collection in the framework or nugget package that implement this case.
Many thanks.

**UPDATE 1**
Currently I have writen two clases trying to find my goal, but both of them have the same problem. When the object is send via WCF, every item is included in the addedItem list. It seems it is a serialization problem, but I have not find any solution.

Here are the classes I have writen

This is the newer one

```
[CollectionDataContract]
        public class ListWithStates<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable 
            where T: INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            [DataMember]
            public List<T> addedItems { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public List<T> updatedItems { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public List<T> removedItems { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public List<T> items { get; set; }

            #region Constructor

            public ListWithStates() : this(new List<T>()) { }

            public ListWithStates(IEnumerable<T> collection)
            {
                this.items = new List<T>(collection);

                InitStateLists();
                CreateEvents();
            }

            private void InitStateLists()
            {
                this.addedItems = new List<T>();
                this.updatedItems = new List<T>();
                this.removedItems = new List<T>();
            }

            private void CreateEvents()
            {
                foreach(T item in this.items)
                    item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
            }

            #endregion


            #region Propiedades

            public int Count
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.items.Count;
                }
            }

            public bool IsReadOnly
            {
                get
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public T this[int index]
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.items[index];
                }

                set
                {
                    RemoveItemFromStateLists(this[index]);
                    this[index] = value;
                    AddItemToStateLists(value);
                }
            }

            #endregion


            #region Implementación de interfaces

            public int IndexOf(T item)
            {
                return this.items.IndexOf(item);
            }

            public void Insert(int index, T item)
            {
                RemoveItemFromStateLists(this.items[index]);
                this.items.Insert(index, item);
                AddItemToStateLists(item);
            }

            public void RemoveAt(int index)
            {
                RemoveItemFromStateLists(this.items[index]);
                this.items.RemoveAt(index);
            }

            public void Add(T item)
            {
                this.items.Add(item);
                AddItemToStateLists(item);
            }

            public void Clear()
            {
                foreach (T item in this.items)
                    RemoveItemFromStateLists(item);

                this.items.Clear();
            }

            public bool Contains(T item)
            {
                return this.items.Contains(item);
            }

            public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
            {
                this.items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
            }

            public bool Remove(T item)
            {
                RemoveItemFromStateLists(item);
                return this.items.Remove(item);
            }

            public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return this.items.GetEnumerator();
            }

            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return this.items.GetEnumerator();
            }

            #endregion


            #region Métodos

            private void AddItemToStateLists(T item)
            {
                if (this.addedItems.Contains(item))
                    return;

                this.addedItems.Add(item);
                item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
            }

            private void UpdateItemFromStateLists(T item)
            {
                if (this.addedItems.Contains(item))
                    return;
                if (this.updatedItems.Contains(item))
                    return;

                this.updatedItems.Add(item);
            }

            private void RemoveItemFromStateLists(T item)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;

                if (this.addedItems.Contains(item))
                {
                    this.addedItems.Remove(item);
                    return;
                }

                if (this.updatedItems.Contains(item))
                {
                    this.updatedItems.Remove(item);
                    return;
                }

                if (!this.removedItems.Contains(item))
                    this.removedItems.Add(item);
            }

            private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!(sender is T))
                    return;

                UpdateItemFromStateLists((T)sender);
            }

            #endregion
        }
```

And this is the older one

```
[CollectionDataContract]
    public class ObservableCollectionWithStates<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<T> addedItems { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<T> updatedItems { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<T> removedItems { get; set; }

        #region Constructor

        public ObservableCollectionWithStates() : base()
        {
            InitStateLists();
            CreateEvents();
        }

        public ObservableCollectionWithStates(List<T> list) : base(list)
        {
            InitStateLists();
            CreateEvents();
        }

        public ObservableCollectionWithStates(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
        {
            InitStateLists();
            CreateEvents();
        }

        private void InitStateLists()
        {
            this.addedItems = new List<T>();
            this.updatedItems = new List<T>();
            this.removedItems = new List<T>();
        }

        private void CreateEvents()
        {
            foreach (T item in this)
                item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
        }

        #endregion


        #region Métodos sobreescritos

        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach(T item in e.OldItems)
                    item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
            }

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
                    item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
            }

            UpdateStateLists(e.Action, e.OldItems, e.NewItems);
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }

        private void UpdateStateLists(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, IList oldItems, IList newItems)
        {
            if (action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (var item in newItems)
                    AddItemToStateLists((T)item);
            }
            else if (action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                foreach (var item in oldItems)
                    RemoveItemFromStateLists((T)item);
            }
            else if (action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                foreach (var item in newItems)
                    AddItemToStateLists((T)item);

                foreach (var item in oldItems)
                    RemoveItemFromStateLists((T)item);
            }
            else if (action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                foreach (var item in oldItems)
                    RemoveItemFromStateLists((T)item);
            }
        }

        #endregion


        #region Métodos propios

        private void AddItemToStateLists(T item)
        {
            if (this.addedItems.Contains(item))
                return;

            this.addedItems.Add(item);
        }

        private void UpdateItemFromStateLists(T item)
        {
            if (this.addedItems.Contains(item))
                return;
            if (this.updatedItems.Contains(item))
                return;

            this.updatedItems.Add(item);
        }

        private void RemoveItemFromStateLists(T item)
        {
            if (this.addedItems.Contains(item))
            {
                this.addedItems.Remove(item);
                return;
            }

            if (this.updatedItems.Contains(item))
            {
                this.updatedItems.Remove(item);
                return;
            }

            if (!this.removedItems.Contains(item))
                this.removedItems.Add(item);
        }

        private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(sender is T))
                return;

            UpdateItemFromStateLists((T)sender);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Show us the class you created.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:
This would be your data model

```
class Items
{
    private List<string> NewItems { get; set; }
    private List<string> UpdatedItems { get; set; }
    private List<string> RemovedItems { get; set; }
}
```

This would be your main list that would get serialized/deserialized

```
        List<Items> ListOfItems = new List<Items>();
```

This should serialize as a list with 3 lists if you are using the base .net serializer.  I think you would be swapping out the List with your complex class of the item in question.  But is should still serialize just the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when I serialized/deserialized the constructor is call and then, every item is added, therefrore every item is included in the NewItem list